# how to prepare dataset for activity recognition

Tags: matlab, image-processing, dataset, activity-recognition

I trying to recognise human activity and I did not find some of these activities in the public datasets.

I am looking for datasets of reading and Lying activities.

Now, I decided to prepare it here in the school. MY question is how to prepare a dataset, is it just a video recording then I split it into image frames??

wish to get your help

Regards

Comment: You should read relevant papers on this topic to figure out the answer. I think this question is too broad for SO.

Comment: a relevant paper for doing dataset?? is it affected by the size, type of image frame. I thought it just load the frames from the video and that is it.

Comment: It is always good to see how other people have done it. Eventually, it may turn out to be as simple as just extracting the frames from a video, but you will get an idea about how many frames to extract, duration of each video in your dataset etc.

Comment: thanks a lot Parag

Answer (score 0):

You may find here the experimental protocol of creating a HAR dataset using smartphone
The description of the dataset is here:
https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Human+Activity+Recognition+Using+Smartphones

The methodology is here:
https://www.elen.ucl.ac.be/Proceedings/esann/esannpdf/es2013-84.pdf